# How to do filtering on complete JQGrid Data

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, mvcjqgrid

I am using JqGrid with asp mvc, I am using select filter on grid headers for filtering.

My grid is having paging , so when i am building select string it will return me only values which are available on current page only. But i am having complete data in my json object on page. so how can i do filtering on entire data of grid.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the answer is in your question. You wrote:

> when i am building select string it will return me only values which
>   are available on current page only.

You can return one page of data, but still make SELECT DESTINCT *on the server side* to get all different values existing in the column. You need just use the value in the select.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have used JQGrid's methods to do this.

```
 var gridTotlaRecords=grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
```

This will returen me complete data of the binded grid.
In my case this is json object , so after getting data, i need to iterate  gridTotlaRecords 's desired column (peroperty) to build select sting.

thanks,
Pavan Tiwari

Comment: Sorry, but I have absolutely no idea what you do. You wrote "I am using select filter on grid headers for filtering". You even don't wrote that you use **local data** or `loadonce: true`. Now you write about to iterate gridTotlaRecords 's desired column (peroperty) to build select sting. Do you want to get the subset of local data, which corresponds the currently applied filter?